# Python - POST multiple headers

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

I'm trying to post some xml to create a forum topic programmatically using python. Basically I need to post xml with the following headers:

Authorization: Basic 
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

This is the code I'm trying to use but it needs BOTH headers in the single request.post():

```
import base64
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

xml = "<xml code here>"
url = 'https://server/forums/atom/forum?id=b7915594-5c46-4ae6-916a-be869aabb327'
userID = 'userid'
password = 'password'

header = {"Content-type": "application/atom+xml"}

r = requests.post(url, headers=header, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userID,password), data=xml)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: You haven't described why you think this doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

what's wrong with

```
header = {"Authorization": "Basic", "Content-type": "application/atom+xml"}
```

?

Comment: Agreed. The [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) just say to pass a dict to the `headers` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The request needs to post the authorization token (example): "Authorization: Basic dG9ueS5tXYJKeWz8oLsfezxeqUtDgh2HjBBdeDfse==" rather then just "Authorization: Basic"

Comment: Ok, what's wrong with `header = { "Authorization": "Basic dG9ueS5tXYJKeWz8oLsfezxeqUtDgh2HjBBdeDfse==", 
"Content-type": "application/atom+xml"}` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to pass the credentials when posting and not add the token to the header...in otherwords, I should be adding my userid/password and then generate the token in the header without having to add it manually to the header.

Comment: That's not what your question is about.

Comment: Apologies for that. The whole purpose is to pass the credentials into the "Authorization" header and post both "Content-Type: application/atom+xml" and "Authorization" in the same request. Hence why I raised the question around passing BOTH headers.

Comment: 4 comments ago you give me example header: `"Authorization: Basic {token}"`, then you sad that adding token to header is not what you want. Now you said that IT IS what you want. Sorry, I'm totally confused.

Comment: @lia1000 I would change your password. Anyone can unencode the password string because it's simply `base64encode("username:password")`, e.g., all someone has to do is `base64decode("dG9ue...==")`. If you can change your username too, you should do that.